# Adjective equivalent of "As old as the hills"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a one-word, more formal adjective for the expression "as old as the hills" ?

The idea is that there is something very old but a little forgotten today (and usually one uses this expression when speaking to someone who doesn't know about the thing).

Example sentences : "This soup is great, you really need to tell us the recipe!" "It's nothing original you know. The recipe is (missing adjective here). The Romans already knew about it."

"There's civil war again in region X, I am a little surprised." "You know, the enmity between ethnic groups Y and Z there is (missing adjective here). We have historical records from ten centuries ago"

Comment: Could the downvoter please clarify his or her motive

Comment: Won't happen.  You've been driveby downvoted.  I'll do my bit to correct, though.

Comment: One possible reason (I am not the downvoter) is you didn't include any context. The following is the rule of this community. ***Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered***. I would advise you to visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help). Please write an example sentence that shows how you would use the word.

Comment: The question looks far better and clearer. +1 :)

Comment: Hyphenate it! An as-old-as-the-hills book.

Comment: Your revised question still isn't sufficient to describe what you want ... you're rejecting a lot of answers that I think fit quite well. Maybe you also want the implication "forgotten today", but "as old as the hills" doesn't carry that implication, either.

Comment: @PeterShor What is lacking in my revised question ? I also have no idea what you mean by "youre rejecting a lot of answers". As far as I know there is no such thing as rejecting answers here (except perhaps for moderators), there is only upvoting/downvoting/not voting answers or accepting/unaccepting them.

Comment: You commented *"this is off topic"* on several answers that to me seemed perfectly good answers to your revised question. This is what I meant by "rejecting" them. If you had instead explained what was actually wrong with them, you might get a better answer.

Comment: @PeterShor I only put "off topic" comments on two answers. Both were written minutes after I posted the question, and in both those comments I pointed to my update for explanation. To summarize, both are obsolete comments on earlier versions an answer.

Comment: Ewan, you say ** The idea is that there is something very old but a little forgotten today**.  Just for the record:  for me, "old as the hills" simply suggests "old".  That phrase does not in fact suggest the *"a little forgotten today"* aspect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple one that seems to closely fit your sample sentences is **age-old**. Admittedly it sounds perhaps a little more natural to say `is an age-old one`, but `is age-old` works for me. It doesn't have the negative connotations of some of the "old" words, yet implies that the subject has been around for a long long time. **timeworn** is in a similar bracket.

Answer (score 14):

***Antediluvian*** literally means "from before the flood."

The **flood** referred to is The flood which covered the Earth, Noah's Flood, Utnapishtim's flood in the Epic of Gilgamesh. Not very appropriate for a recipe, or gathering.

> : [from] before the flood described in the
>   Bible. 2. a : made ... a long time ago "an 
>   antediluvian automobile"  b : extremely primitive [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antediluvian)

***Ancient Recipes*** in age sequence, resourced from the family.

**Traditional**  since 1950
**Mother's** Marmalade 1945.
**Grandmothers** 'Orange Wine.' 1900.
**Family**  mince pies 1890 superseded 
**Historic** Chutney from 1780 adopted by Uncle John.

Sadly we don't have a **clan** haggis, or a **tribal** cava cava.

Comment: Why is this off topic now? It still fits for me.

Comment: Is cava cava cava ?

Comment: @JoeBlow As I understood it Cava is a root vegetable eaten in Oceanic islands, which requires very careful preparation to remove alkaloids. And Cava cava is a tribal drink needing even more careful preparation. I think the last time I read about it Prince Charles was sharing a cup with Solomon Islanders; but since then it seems to have changed its name to Kava and pops up in British Health Food shops in dropper bottles.

Comment: Hi Hugh .. fascinating!   Funnily enough cava is I guess what "Champagne" is called in italy ...

Answer (score 5):

Some obvious words are *ancient, primaeval, primordial, mediaeval, paleolithic*, with phrases available such as *from the stone age, since Adam was a boy, from the Dark Ages*, among others.

Answer (score 5):

Consider,

***immemorial***

> : very old or ancient : from a time so long ago that it cannot be remembered [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/immemorial)
>
> : originating in the distant past; very old : *an immemorial custom* [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/immemorial)

[*existing] **since time immemorial***

> : since a very long time ago. Literally, since time before recorded history. [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/since+time+immemorial)

Answer (score 4):

**prehistoric** is a possible adjective that fits your question, but it really depends on context [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prehistoric):

> : very old or outdated

Comment: Rather your comment is off topic. Examples of [prehistoric recipes](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22prehistoric+recipes%22) and [prehistoric enmities](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22prehistoric%20enmity%22)

Comment: Ewan, how is this and others off topic now? This sounds just right to me still, except maybe it doesn't fit the particular examples. Can you specify why this isn't a good fit anymore?

Comment: @macraf I stand corrected. I didn't know taht "prehistoric" could be used in this sense

Answer (score 2):

***[Antique](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/antique)*** may fit in your context:

> - Of or belonging to ancient times, especially of, from, or characteristic of ancient Greece or Rome.

or you may use the expression :

***[lost in the mists of time](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lost+in+the+mists+of+time)***:

> - if something is lost in the mists of time, everyone has forgotten it because it happened such a long time ago.
>
>   - *The true significance of these symbols has become lost in the mists of time.*

The Free Dictionary

Comment: *"... mists of time"* is the only answer here, it seems, which addresses the *"a little forgotten today"* aspect ... I think.

Answer (score 2):

Consider **since the dawn of time**.

Example: *Donkey's milk is an age-old product used since the dawn of time*.

Answer (score 2):

***Century-old*** and ***centuries-old*** are some familiar adjectives for your contexts.

*Google Books* results for:

- [*centuries-old recipe*](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&tbm=bks&q=%22centuries-old+recipe%22)
- [*century-old recipe*](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&tbm=bks&q=%22century-old+recipe%22)
- [*centuries-old enmity*](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22centuries-old+enmity%22&safe=off&tbm=bks&start=0)

Answer (score 1):

Just FWIW you can indeed use

***forgotten***

in the sense of, "something that was once extremely famous, but surprisingly is now largely unknown."

For example: in 500 years you might hear "WOW. These 'Rolling Stones' are totally amazing. Why haven't we heard of them like 'The Beatles'?"  "Ah yes. 'The Stones'. The forgotten idols of the '1900s'!"

Or, "WOW, everyone knows Mona Lisa but check out this sable thing!" "Ah yes, it's a forgotten masterpiece of his..."

Some early TV shows that were the biggest thing in the world at the time are becoming forgotten megahits .. say, *Moonlighting*.

and so on.

So, you can use that common form in English, *the forgotten X*, for the exact sense you outline.  So, in your actual examples,

*The recipe is a forgotten basic. The Romans already used it all the time.*

*The tension between Y and Z is a forgotten conflict - warring goes back 500 years between them.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that [Ancient](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ancient) hasn't been given as an answer already - the standard definition seems to perfectly match the requirements:

> ancient (ˈeɪnʃənt) adj
>   1. dating from very long ago:

Comment: Ancient is mentioned in Hugh's answer